# Is the word "fit" a noun in this sentence?

Tags: nouns, phrasal-verbs

> He hadn't told either Phoebe or Deidre about his daughter. The child wasn't precisely a secret. She simply didn't visit often. The public had seen ***fit*** to ignore her existence in the long ago scandal, and Calder supposed he’d simply become used to being about Meggie.
>   (Celeste Bradley, The Duke Next Door)

The word ***fit*** seems like a noun functioning as the complement of *seen*. Dictionaries say that *fit* takes an article when used as a noun, so I'm not sure if the word is really used as a noun in the above example.

Is it a noun?

Comment: Nope.  It's an adjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Fit" is an adjective meaning acceptable, proper, or appropriate.

You might say, "After the repairs, the car was again FIT for use on the highway." It is fairly common to say that something is "fit and proper", either in general or for a particular purpose, like, "Bob is a fit and proper gentleman", or "It is fit and proper to kiss on the third date", though this is a somewhat anachronistic usage. And you can say "he saw fit to do this", meaning, "he thought it was appropriate to do this".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. "to see fit" is "to think (something) is appropriate".

Comment: I agree completely with your definition of "fit" but OP is asking about the phrasal verb "to see fit" which, while one can intuit a meaning based on the definition of "fit," is in fact an idiom unto itself.

Comment: @jim Sure, and no doubt I could have been more clear. I was trying to say that the meaning of the idiom can be deduced from the basic definitions of the word.

Answer (score 0):

[***to see fit***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/see+fit) is a phrasal verb meaning:

> to decide to do something. *If I see fit to return, I'll bring Bill with me. She'll do it if she sees fit.*

I will add that the decision is usually based on perceived (*to see*) suitability (*fit*).
So the public had decided to ignore her existence...